# How is python's fractions.limit_denominator implemented?

Tags: python, fractions

```
limit_denominator(max_denominator=1000000)
Finds and returns the closest Fraction to self that has denominator at most max_denominator. This method is useful for finding rational approximations to a given floating-point number:

>>>
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> Fraction('3.1415926535897932').limit_denominator(1000)
Fraction(355, 113)
```

It shouldn't be something like trying a/999, b/998, c/997.. and find best approximations.

Comment: FWIW, as the original author of `Fraction.limit_denominator`, it's long bothered me that the proof of correctness existed partly in my head, partly in scribbled notes, and partly in online and book-form resources. I needed to modify the code recently, and it took *way* too long to remember how it worked. So 10 years later, I've finally posted a proof: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95723

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `fractions` module is written in Python and you can just look at the source code. It contains the following comment.

```
    # Algorithm notes: For any real number x, define a *best upper
    # approximation* to x to be a rational number p/q such that:
    #
    #   (1) p/q >= x, and
    #   (2) if p/q > r/s >= x then s > q, for any rational r/s.
    #
    # Define *best lower approximation* similarly.  Then it can be
    # proved that a rational number is a best upper or lower
    # approximation to x if, and only if, it is a convergent or
    # semiconvergent of the (unique shortest) continued fraction
    # associated to x.
    #
    # To find a best rational approximation with denominator <= M,
    # we find the best upper and lower approximations with
    # denominator <= M and take whichever of these is closer to x.
    # In the event of a tie, the bound with smaller denominator is
    # chosen.  If both denominators are equal (which can happen
    # only when max_denominator == 1 and self is midway between
    # two integers) the lower bound---i.e., the floor of self, is
    # taken.
```

Comment: Looks like a binary search, squeezing x  between "best lower" and "best upper" approximations

Comment: @ThomasAhle No, it's not a binary search. It involves continued fractions. [The Wikipedia article on continued fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) has [a section](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Continued_fraction&oldid=1030991834#Best_rational_approximations) on the theory behind this. (I had once written a [blog post](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/not-all-best-rational-approximations-are-the-convergents-of-the-continued-fraction/) on this, though it's nothing special and the Wikipedia article is probably a better read.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: "Binary search" isn't totally off the mark, from the right perspective. The continued fraction development is traversing the Stern-Brocot tree, and then accelerating that traversal by using full-blown divisions instead of simple subtractions. The article "Continued Fractions without Tears" by Ian Richards is a really nice exposition of this idea: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/1982/0025570x.di021121.02p0002y.pdf . OTOH, the proof of correctness doesn't actually need continued fractions: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/95723

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thanks for sharing! (And thanks for `limit_denominator`; I've used it frequently. Before I learned of it I had written my own [web tool](https://shreevatsa.net/fraction/best) that had to be used manually…) I'll study the sources you mentioned. Meanwhile IMO I still wouldn't call it binary search even if it traverses a conceptual tree that happens to be binary: the main thing about binary search is using a *test* (typically, comparison) to determine which half to explore further in, and that's missing here AFAICT. (The Richards article pointed to Stark's book which I'm enjoying…)

Comment: @MarkDickinson Ah after reading the article by Richards I understand what you mean: if you implement the algorithm differently (what the article calls "the slow continued fraction method" or the "Farey process") then it is indeed a binary search. So this could be viewed as an optimized version of a binary search (in which case whether to still call it binary search is another question…). I'll try to digest all this; thanks again!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: Yes, I'll agree that calling the current algorithm a binary search is a bit of a stretch. :-)